# Show JSON Dictionary in SwiftUI List

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm attempting to iterate over a Dictionary of Objects in my swift app and show them in a list. I keep getting the error Value of type '[Note]' has no member 'prettyUpdatedString'. Where am I going wrong here?

UPDATE: Thanks to the input from community members, I have been able to compile the code, but the Data is still not showing in the list. No errors are being thrown, but the area is simply blank. See Screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

DATA:

```
[
{
id: 2867,
type: "TechNote",
isSolution: false,
prettyUpdatedString: "1 day ago <strong>Cody Brown</strong> said",
mobileNoteText: "Attempted contact, left voicemail no anwser.",
isTechNote: true,
isHidden: false,
workTime: "0"
},
{
id: 2863,
type: "TechNote",
isSolution: true,
prettyUpdatedString: "1 day ago <strong>Cody Brown</strong> said",
mobileNoteText: "Computer is repaired and ready to be picked up. Please come to the High School Wednesdays (1pm-2pm). If you have a loaner computer please bring it along with the the student.",
isTechNote: true,
isHidden: false,
workTime: "0"
},
{
id: 2818,
type: "TechNote",
isSolution: false,
prettyUpdatedString: "2 weeks ago <strong>Cody Brown</strong> said",
mobileNoteText: "Sent to AGI for repair.",
isTechNote: true,
isHidden: false,
workTime: "0"
},
{
id: 2814,
type: "TechNote",
isSolution: false,
prettyUpdatedString: "2 weeks ago <strong>Cody Brown</strong> said",
mobileNoteText: "Brought to Office",
isTechNote: true,
isHidden: false,
workTime: "0"
},
{
id: 2790,
type: "TechNote",
isSolution: false,
prettyUpdatedString: "2 weeks ago <strong>Seth Duncan</strong> said",
mobileNoteText: "Left VM",
isTechNote: true,
isHidden: true,
workTime: "0"
},
{
id: 2717,
type: "TechNote",
isSolution: false,
prettyUpdatedString: "2 weeks ago <strong>Seth Duncan</strong> said",
mobileNoteText: "<br/> We will be at the OHS Front Office from 1-2PM on Wednesdays to assist with computer issues",
isTechNote: true,
isHidden: false,
workTime: "0"
}
]
```

Fetching Data

```
import SwiftUI

struct Note: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var prettyUpdatedString: String
    var mobileNoteText: String
}

class FetchTicketNotes: ObservableObject {
    func getTicketNotes(id: Int, userApi: String, completion: @escaping ([Note]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "URL HERE") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            let ticketNotes = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Note].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(ticketNotes)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

In View

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var ticketStatusAction = TicketStatusAction()
    @ObservedObject var createTicketNote = CreateTicketNote()
    @State var ticket: [TicketDetails] = []
    @State var ticketNotes: [Note] = []
    @State private var showingNoteAlert = false
    @State private var showingOpenAlert = false
    @State private var showingPendingAlert = false
    @State private var showingDepotAlert = false
    @State private var showingCloseAlert = false
    @State private var note: String = ""
    @ObservedObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()

    var id: Int
    var displayClient: String
    @Binding var userApi: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                if !ticket.isEmpty {
                           Text(self.ticket.first?.location.locationName ?? "")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding()
                           }
                
                Text("\(displayClient) - \(id)")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(size:20))
                    .padding()

                Divider()
                
                Text("Status")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                
                if !ticket.isEmpty {
                    Text(self.ticket.first?.statustype.statusTypeName ?? "")
                    .padding()
                }
                
                Text("Details")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
                
                if !ticket.isEmpty {
                    Text(clearMarkdown(on: self.ticket.first?.detail ?? ""))
                        .padding()
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    
                    Text("Room Number")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                    
                    Text(self.ticket.first?.ticketCustomFields.first(where: {$0.definitionId == 14})?.restValue ?? "NOT PROVIDED")
                    .padding()
                    
                    Text("Computer Number")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                    
                    Text(self.ticket.first?.ticketCustomFields.first(where: {$0.definitionId == 11})?.restValue ?? "NOT PROVIDED")
                    .padding()
                
                    Text("Phone Number")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                    
                    Text(self.ticket.first?.ticketCustomFields.first(where: {$0.definitionId == 15})?.restValue ?? "NOT PROVIDED")
                    .padding()
                }
                
                
                Divider()
                
                Text("Notes")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
                
                List(ticketNotes) { ticketNote in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                        Text(ticketNote.prettyUpdatedString)
                        .padding()
                        
                        Text(ticketNote.mobileNoteText)
                        .padding()
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                FetchTicketNotes().getTicketNotes(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { ticketNotes in
                    self.ticketNotes = ticketNotes
                }
                FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                    self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                }
            }
            
            Divider()

               Section(header: Text("Create New Note")
                   .fontWeight(.bold)
                   .padding()
                   .padding(10)
                   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)) {
                       
                   TextField("Enter your note", text: $note)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 350)
                    .padding(15)

                   
                   Button(action: {
                       self.showingNoteAlert = true
                   }) {
                       Text("Submit Note")
                       .frame(width: 300)
                       .padding(15)
                       .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                       .background(Color.orange)
                       .cornerRadius(5)
                   }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()
                   ).actionSheet(isPresented:self.$showingNoteAlert) {
                       ActionSheet(
                           title: Text("Are you sure you want to add this note to \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                           message: Text("\(self.note)"),
                           buttons: [
                        .default(Text("Submit"))
                            {
                                self.createTicketNote.CreateNoteAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, techNote: self.note);
                                self.note = "";
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                    FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                                        self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        .cancel(){
                            self.note = ""
                            }])
                   }
               }
            
            Divider()

            Section(header: Text("Change Ticket Status")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
                .padding(10)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)) {
                                    
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingOpenAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Open")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingOpenAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want change \(displayClient)'s ticket to Open?"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("Open"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 1);
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                    FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                                        self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingPendingAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Pending")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingPendingAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to set \(displayClient)'s ticket to Pending?"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("Pending"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 2);
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                    FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                                        self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDepotAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Depot")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingDepotAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to depot \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("Depot"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 6);
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                    FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                                        self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingCloseAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Close")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingCloseAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to close \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Close"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 3);
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                    FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                                        self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.padding()
        .padding(.bottom, keyboard.currentHeight)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.16))
    }
}
```

Comment: The decoding part cannot work. The root object is an array (note the enclosing `[]`) and there is neither a key `note` nor `id`.

Comment: Ok, then how would I go about showing the data if I can't decode it?

Comment: Delete the struct `TicketNotes` and decode `[Note].self` and remove one `note` in `Text(clearMarkdown(on: note.prettyUpdatedString))` and in the other occurrence. And you have to adjust some types.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors here. First, update the decoding and completion block of `getTicketNotes` method parameter to `[TicketNotes]`.

```
class FetchTicketNotes: ObservableObject {
    func getTicketNotes(id: Int, userApi: String, completion: @escaping ([Note]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "LINK HERE") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            let ticketNotes = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Note].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(ticketNotes)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Then modify `.onAppear`,

```
.onAppear {
    //...
    FetchTicketNotes().getTicketNotes(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { ticketNotes in
        self.ticketNotes = ticketNotes
    }
}
```

Finally,

```
@State var ticketNotes: [Note] = []
//...
Text(clearMarkdown(on: note.prettyUpdatedString))
```

Comment: Check the update. You need to decode `[Note]` and update `ticketNotes` in `DetailsView`.

Comment: So, the good news is, this is not throwing any errors and I can see the data when I debug, but the bad news is the data is not showing up in the app. I'll update the code and a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but it worked for my situation. I did find the data I was looking for withing the [TicketDetails] JSON, so it made this a little less complicates. In my .onAppear function I captured the relevant data.

Declared the variable

```
@State var ticketNotes: [Notes] = []
```

Changed onAppear

```
.onAppear {
                FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                    self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                    self.ticketNotes = ticketDetails.notes
                }
            }
```

I iterated over each item in the Array with ForEach

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(ticketNotes, id: \.self) {ticketNote in
                Text(clearMarkdown(on: "\(ticketNote.prettyUpdatedString) '\(ticketNote.mobileNoteText)'"))
                .padding()
            }
        }
```